# r- Using sum and match to find first occurrence of a high frequency

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, lapply

I have several data frames in wide format imported from dbf. So every column is a date and every row is an observation. Thus for every day i have between 500-2000 observations depending on the size of the geographic shape i am looking at. For the purposes of reproducible I created 2 dummy data frames with a range of values I may see in my actual data frames.

```
Data1<- data.frame(replicate(10, sample(0:1000, 20, rep= TRUE)))

Data<- data.frame(replicate(10, sample(0:1000, 20, rep= TRUE)))
```

Since I have many of these data frames I have put them in a list so I can run functions on many at once.

```
filenames<- mget(ls(pattern= 'Data'))
```

Now my issue is that I am trying to write a function to count the number of occurrences in each column where values are within the range 0-100. I can accomplish this with

```
library(plyr)
Datacount<- ldply(Data, function(x) length(which(x>=0 & x<=100)))
```

Then i need to be able to match the first column instance (date) in which this counted number is greater than 10% of the total number of observations per column. So for a dataframe with 20 observations I would want the first date where the number of cells between 0-100 is greater than 2. I previously accomplished this using apply (where "V1" is the column name containing the counts)

```
Datamatch<- apply (Datacount["V1"]>2,2,function(x) match (TRUE,x))
```

My question is whether there is a way I can combine these functions into one process that I can employ into either a for loop over "filenames" or using one of the lapply family functions?

For detail here is an example of a single function I built to run across each row of the dataframe. This gives me a column index of the last date where each row value is <= 100. Then i used lapply to loop over all dataframes in my list and append the results of the function to the original dataframe.

icein<- function(dataframe){
  dataframe$icein<- apply(dataframe, 1, function(x){tail(which(x<=100), 1)})
  dataframe
}
list2env(lapply(filenames, icein), envir= .GlobalEnv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading all the 'Data' into a `list`, loop over the `list` with `map`, get the `mean` of logical vector (`between(., 0, 100)`) check if it greater than or equal to 2, `unlist` the data.frame, wrap with `which` to get the position index, extract the `first` one

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
n <- 0.2
mget(ls(pattern= 'Data')) %>%
      map_int(~ .x %>% 
                  summarise_all(~ mean(between(., 0, 100)) >= n) %>% 
                  unlist %>%
                  which %>%
                  first)
```

Comment: thank you, @akrun I can see here that the 0.2 would still be manually written. Would there be a way for 10% of cells to be written as a function of the number of observations in `Data` so the function can be called for dataframes with different numbers of observations?      something like `round(0.1*(nrow))`

Comment: @JamieVarney. It is automated.  The `0.2` is a threshold value passed.  Here, the `mean` calculates the percentage of values that are between 0 and 100.  The `>= 0.2` is only checking whether it is greater than 20 percent or not

Comment: @JamieVarney. when you do `round(0.1*(nrow))`, the `0.1` iis manual right.  It is the same happening here becausee the `mean` does create the percentage based on the number of rows. e.g. `v1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE); mean(v1)`

Comment: ah ok thank you, i was missunderstanding the mean of the vector being passed